# Filling upper or under some contour curves which are related to different data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour, contourf

By using `ax.contour` I plotted three contour curves which are related to three different data and I would like to fill the under and/or upper space of these curves with a specific color. Could you please let me know how I can do this? Here is the code and you can find the regarded fig too.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

CS1 = ax.contour(X, Y, Z1, [2])
ax.clabel(CS1, inline=True, fontsize=10)

CS2 = ax.contour(X, Y, Z2, [11])
ax.clabel(CS2, inline=True, fontsize=10)

CS3 = ax.contour(X, Y, Z3, [580])
ax.clabel(CS3, inline=True, fontsize=10)


plt.show()
```

To clarify more, in fact, Z1, Z2 and Z3 are three different data and I plotted three different contour curves for them (as you can see in the fig), I want to fill upper the Z1 curve with red and under the Z2 and Z3 with blue and green respectively.

[image: Three contours for three different data named Z1,Z2 and Z3]

The filling methods in Matplotlip do not work here for these contour curves. Moreover, using for instance the method, `ax.contourf(X, Y, Z1, levels=[2, 3], colors='red', alpha=0.3)` does not work since it is useful when you have only one data (Z1), however, here I have three data (Z1,Z2 and Z3) with three contours.

Comment: Well, you could create a new function from the given ones. E.g. something like `ax.contour(X, Y, (Z1<=2)&(11<=Z2), [0, np.inf])`, depending on where the functions are positive. Things would be simpler to explain if you'd add some reproducible test code.